# URIError: Failed to decode param '/<myusername>/<projectname>/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uri

I am trying to revive an old React app that I coded a year and a half ago.

I cloned it and installed all of the dependencies, but when I do 'npm start', it just loads a blank page and throws the error:

"URIError: Failed to decode param '///%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json'"

I am honestly not sure where to go from here.

Here is what my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "nosmallstreamer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/chaselancaster/nosmallstreamer-frontend.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/chaselancaster/nosmallstreamer-frontend/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/chaselancaster/nosmallstreamer-frontend#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is what my index.html looks like in the public folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" /> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is what my manifest.json looks like in the public folder:

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It looks like this was originally created with Create React App. I would assume it has a `public` folder. What are its contents?

Comment: It contains the index.html and manifest.json!

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide the index.html?

Comment: Totally going to add it now!

Answer (score 5):

Try changing your `homepage` in your `package.json` file to: `"/"` instead of using your GitHub repo's URL.  `react-scripts run` (which is what `npm start` runs) seems to use the domain from the `homepage` as the root from which to serve the app.

Answer (score 2):

In your index.html, try changing

```
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
```

to:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/public/manifest.json" />
```

This may be the only way to solve it without ejecting the project.

Comment: Tried it, but no luck! For some reason, the full name of the project does not show up in the URL bar. It displays "http://localhost:3000/chaselancaster/nosmallstreamer-fronten".
However, the name of the project is "nosmallstreamer-frontend". Would that have anything to do with it?