# npm start in React app opens different url unpredictably

Tags: reactjs, npm

Tried to run `npm start` on a project I hadn't looked at in a couple weeks and when I did it opens up `localhost:3000/myname/partofmyprojectname` instead of just `localhost:3000/`

When I go to `localhost:3000/` there's an error in my terminal

Really confusing because it worked last time I tried it and I didn't change anything I don't think.

Answer (score 2):

As I was making this question I found the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64922735/urierror-failed-to-decode-param-myusername-projectname-public-url-manif):

In my package.json, `"homepage"`'s value was the path to the readme in the github repo: `"https://github.com/myname/my-app-frontend#readme"` (don't know how that happened). I just changed that to `'/'`.

I'm thinking maybe my version of react-scripts updated and `npm start` was deferring to the homepage key in the `package.json` but not totally sure.